# Grouping intervals in a few passes

Tags: algorithm

I have lots of intervals (x,y) and I would like to group them together. The rule is that a set of intervals is in the same group if they are all nested in one member of the group except for one which is the largest interval they are all nested in. For example, (1,7), (2,4),(2,9), (8,9)  can be split into two groups (1,7),(2,4) and (2,9),(8,9). Of course this is not unique but it is minimal in the sense that you can't have fewer groups.

To make it more complicated I can't afford to read in all the data at once as it is too large.

I can sort the data offline by the first element in each pair, for example.

What is a good algorithm for this problem?

Comment: How are you going to keep the group structure (which is more bits of information than your input data) in memory if you cannot even afford to read all the input at once?

Comment: I can write to disk. Ideally the algorithm would work in a small number of passes keeping a limited amount of data in ram in each pass or failing that would be nice out of memory like merge sort. The group structure could just be a group name for each interval or a pointer like in the disjoint set structure I was thinking.

Comment: Looks like `UNION FIND` to me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @wildplasser How would you use union find to solve this problem?

Comment: More or less like @Jarek D's answer: for every new pair either merge (and/or split) it with an existing cluster (the enclosing interval will be "on top"), or create a new cluster. A partial overlap will always split, and a full overlap will always absorb, with the biggest one "on top". Multiple overlaps could cause (cascading?) combinatorial explosions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the intervals by nondecreasing x, breaking ties by nonincreasing y. Scan the intervals in order. While there exist more intervals, make the first one remaining the enclosing interval of a new group and, while possible, add each successive interval to the group.

Suppose that there exist two intervals [x, y] and [x', y'] such that x <= x' <= y' <= y. Then we can show that [x', y'] is not the enclosing interval of a group, and hence that the grouping is minimal. If [x, y] = [x', y'], then it is clear that [x, y] and [x', y'] are assigned to the same group. Otherwise, the interval [x, y] sorts before [x', y'], since either x < x', or x = x' and y' < y. The enclosing interval [x'', y''] that is active when [x', y'] is scanned satisfies x'' <= x' (by the sort order) and y' <= y <= y'' (since the y coordinate of the active enclosing interval is nondecreasing over time). Hence, [x', y'] does not start a group.

Comment: Thanks but how would (0,10),(11,20),(2,3) work? Your answer wouldn't nest (2,3) in (0,10) would it?

Comment: Since the x-coordinates are distinct, the sorted order is simply (0, 10), (2, 3), (11, 20). Start a group with (0, 10). The next interval scanned is (2, 3), which is added to (0, 10)'s group. (11, 20) begins a new group.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the input groups by the size of x-y biggest first (offline).

Go over the list of groups and for every group check if it is contained in one of the groups that came before it.
If so - remove it from the list and mark it in a file (files explanation soon)
If not - it's a group

Files:
keep a structure of files named according to the index of the group in the input list.
Create the files as you go, and in any file keep all the (x,y) pairs in them.

This will give you a relatively good answer, but I'm unsure if it's the optimal one.

Times:

- sort = o(nlogn)
- Passing through the list can be up to o(n^2) in the worst case (if no groups intersect)

Comment: The sorting step is fine. The question is how to do the checking afterwards quickly. N^2 is much too slow sadly.

Comment: The actual processing time is dependent on the input. if there is no intersection it's o(n^2), but if they all intersect (the 1st group contains all the others) it's o(n).

Answer (score 0):

It might be simplistic but based on the assumptions you have given should be appropriate. It is assuming that input data is an endless, unknown stream/queue

1. Take item from the queue.
2. If first one create new group.
3. If not first one traverse existing groups and put into first matching group.
4. If cannot be put in any group create new group
5. repeat the process

you can apply additional limitations here (max group size ect.)

Comment: Making step 3 fast is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

1. Sort the intervals with the range start(first element).
2. Take the first interval from sorted set. keep it in memory. add to a list.
3. while (take the next one)

   ```
       a. it can be fully inclusive in any of the elements in the list, add it to the group of contained interval.
       b. Partial inclusive, add a new member in memory. append it to the list.
       c. totally Exclusive, add it to the list, remove previous elements in the list and persist in disk.
   ```

Comment: This looks quadratric time with high memory needs sadly.

Comment: It can't be quadratic, you could use binary search to check the contained interval in the list, as the list is sorted by the first element anyway

Comment: Even persisting step shall happen for every interval if it lies in any of the larger intervals set exist in memory, eagerly. So the worst case memory needed would be the exact range of larger interval in memory.